# Localized accelerators (JMenuItem hotkeys) in Swing

Tags: java, swing, internationalization, keystroke, acceleratorkey

I am working in an English app on a german laptop, over a spanish OS.

Even if I explictly set Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH) at the beggining of my app, I am seeing the hotkexs in the menu as

```
CTRL + Mayúsculas + C
```

instead of

```
CTRL + SHIFT + C
```

that I passed to the KeyStroke object.

Is not only that word does not get localized to english as I specified, but also that it maps SHIFT key to MAYUS (CAPS LOCK in english), so I guess this is not only a language issue, but keymap´s as well.

So how can I impose english for all the GUI components?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have to make sure that you set the locale before any toolkit code is executed. The following code shows the effect: if you move the `Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);` to any other line it will show the default accelerator names again.

Instead of setting the locale inside your code you may also append the following argument to the VM:

```
-Duser.language=DE
```

[image: locale menu]

```
public class MenuLocale {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

                JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
                JMenu menu = new JMenu("Menu");
                JMenuItem menuitem = new JMenuItem("Menuitem");    
                menuitem.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('X', KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK));

                f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
                menubar.add(menu);
                menu.add(menuitem);

                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I put it in the first line of my code after main method declaration and it does not work :'(

Comment: Be aware that your main method is not part of a JFrame. That was the trap I ran into...